# Load and control a 3D model (.ply format only)

Tags: 3d, uwp, windows-10-universal

*That's my first question in StackOverflow so... Hello World!*

I'm working in a catalog-like application. I made the list controls, parsers and all main front and back-end work… But the client now wants to change the PNG image for a 3D model of their products.

Anyone knows how to add a PLY reader which load the file and allows user to rotate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to rotate that 3D model or rotate the PNG image? What is PLY reader here in details?

Generally speaking, in UWP there are three possible things which may related to your request:

1. you can use [SwapChainPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel) to load your sample model. For a sample you can check this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b/view/SourceCode#content).
2. You can also create a Unity UWP experience app and here is a [demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/uwp-experiences/tree/master/apps/weather)
3. If you just mean you need to change a image's rotation, please check this official doc([Point Based ratation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/pointer-input-animations)) and then the demo code on [Github UI labs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2015063/PointerRotate/PointerRotate.xaml.cs). The sample shows how you can rotate the image based on the 3D rotation.

For more details you have to be specific about your request.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I want to load a [.ply file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) that was generated by a 3D scanner.
I will try the first and second possible solutions later.